# App crash detection by AspNetCoreModule

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net-core, hosting, health-monitoring

The new [AspNetCoreModule module](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/hosting/aspnet-core-module.html) just like IIS somehow detects when an application crashes and restarts it. How is it implemented? Just by asking Windows if a process still exists or something more subtle (like a RPC call maybe)? What happens if a process just hangs resulting in HTTP timeouts?

Answer (score 1):

When AspNetCoreModule creates the child process, it immediately check the whether the child process is up by connecting it via socket and exist code. If the child process is up, the module calls RegisterWaitForSingleObject with processInformation.hProcess and some callback, so that if child process exists, the callback will be called. In the case, the child process hangs, the module will return 502 back to the client after timeout and will not kill the child process.

Comment: Thank you, very detailed explanation! Can the module be configured to kill/restart a child process if it doesn't respond after a certain timeout?